# Apple p8 and p12 for push notification

Tags: ios, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I have an app that needs APN service.

After I created p8 (which is recommended by Braze) for apn service, I noticed the push notification for the particular app is still "configurable" as opposed to "enabled" under Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles - App IDs - . So I went ahead and created p12 certificates for this particular app as well.

Currently push notification is very unstable, not idea what's going on behind APN, error gives me "BadDeviceToken sent to "

My questions:

1. After creates the generic p8 key, does the push notification works without the need to configure p12 certificate for each particular app? Why is the still showing "configurable" instead of "enabled"?
2. If I create both p8 and p12 for push notification, which one should I use in Braze?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> After creates the generic p8 key, does the push notification works
>   without the need to configure p12 certificate for each particular app?
>   Why is the still showing "configurable" instead of "enabled"?

Showing "Configurable" is correct for Push Notifications.

> If I create both p8 and p12 for push notification, which one should I
>   use in Braze?

Just stick to p8 auth key, it is a more recommended nowadays to handle push notifications and also recommended by Braze as you have mentioned.